# how to keep nohup from killing java process that waits for stdin linux

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have a java program that is executed on command line (Bash Linux). Once executed the program continues to run, reading stdin until the user inputs 'quit'.

Sometimes I would like to **nohup** the program so it continues to run even if my remote connection is closed. The problem is that when I attempt to nohup the program as demonstrated below it seems that its prompt for stdin kills nohup and terminates the program.

> Example: $ nohup java -jar myApp.jar

I have tried redirecting the program's output to **2>/dev/null** per other suggestions as well as running it in the background using **&**. Neither prevents nohup from being killed.

I cannot use **disown** because once I run the program I lose the command prompt to the program.

Comment: Any reason not to use `tmux` or `screen` instead? You may be able to sidestep the issue that way.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Thanks, I was actually not familiar with those. I don't currently have either installed. I think I'll get screen and give it a try.

Comment: I would personally recommend `tmux`, as it's a bit more user-friendly than `screen` in my opinion. If you give me a minute I'll write up an answer that tells you exactly how to use it for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your program running in the background, run `tmux`:

```
tmux
```

This will open up a tmux shell, where you can run your program:

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

Then to detach from the tmux session, type `ctrl-b` then `d`. Your program will continue to run in the background.

To reattach to your program's shell at a later time (to kill it or view its output), run `tmux attach`.

Answer (score 0):

Although **tmux** solved my problem, I kept poking around and playing with **disown** until I got it to work.  I was able to keep the java process running after logoff by piping it a super-long **sleep** command (suggested in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68246/simulate-empty-stdin-to-detached-command)), running it in the background, and then running **disown**. Like this:

> $ sleep 999999999 | java -jar myApp.jar&
>
> $ disown

So, I'm going to stick with **tmux**, but I just thought I'd share this as it worked as well for my problem.